# Very weird samba share (net use) client error code 1219, what happens?

Tags: samba

I'm facing such a weird problem.

From a freshly started Windows 8.1 client PC, I issue two `net use` commands to connect a Samba shared folder.

```
net use H: \\10.22.3.84\h /user:guest

net use L: \\10.22.3.84\incoming /user:guest
```

If I request to type password interactively the second `net use` fails with error code 1219.

> System error 1219 has occurred.
>
> Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user,
> using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all
> previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again.

[image]

Then, I reboot my client PC again, this time, I explicit assign password(although just an empty string) on `net use` command line, they both succeed.

```
net use H: \\10.22.3.84\h /user:guest ""

net use L: \\10.22.3.84\incoming /user:guest ""
```

[image]

BTW: The samba server is a Windows 10(22H2) machine.

I'd like to know, why case B fails? Or any suggestion I can peek inside the difference of [case A,B] and [case C,D]?

### ==== Supplement info ====

[2023-10-19] For case A, C, D, the server side compmgmt.msc always shows the client user-name is "guest", not "chj".

[image: compmgmt.msc shows Samba clients]

Comment: You authenticated as you connected to H: drive, so I assume all you need for the second drive is `net use L: \\10.22.3.84\incoming`. You should be able to forget about the `/user:guest` part.

Comment: Hello Bib, I tried `net use L: \\10.22.3.84\incoming` in lieu of case #B, and it really succeeds (just call it #B1), as you have assumed. But I still don't know why. For each case, #A, #B, #B1, #C, #D, the server side always shows the client name is `guest`, then why the difference?